# Inner join or Left outer join based on condition

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to add a condition in my query to do INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN

These are the two queries

```
   USE [tisonline]

   SELECT TOP 1000 *
   FROM Jobs AS j
   LEFT OUTER JOIN JobQueries AS jq ON j.JobID = jq.JobID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Agents AS agt ON agt.AgentID = jq.AgentID
   where j.isMigrated = 1 

   SELECT TOP 1000 *
   FROM Jobs AS j
   INNER JOIN JobQueries AS jq ON j.JobID = jq.JobID 
   INNER JOIN Agents AS agt ON agt.AgentID = jq.AgentID
   where j.isMigrated = 0
```

Schema of the Following tables:

```
Job: {
        [JobID]
        ,[JobGUID]
      ,[Duplicate]
      ,[CreateByTisForAgency]
      ,[TisClientCode]
      ,[AgencyID]
      ,[AgencyName]
      ,[BookingAgentID]
      ,[LanguageID]
      ,[ReqGender]
      ,[AnotherGender]
      ,[ProfessionalAccLevelReq]
      ,[InstructionsToInterpreter]
}
  JobQueryTable
  {
   [JobQueryID]
      ,[JobID]
      ,[JobGuid]
      ,[NonEnglishSpeakerName]
      ,[DuplicateJob]
      ,[JobDate]
      ,[JobStartTime]
      ,[JobEndTime]
      ,[JobState]
      ,[JobTier]
      ,[LanguageID]
      ,[AgencyID]
      ,[AgencyName]
      ,[AgentID]
   }
Agent Tabe 
{  
[AgentID]
      ,[AgentGUID]
      ,[Position]
      ,[Section]
      ,[Role]
      ,[AgentDetails_PersonalDetailsID]
      ,[Agency_AgencyID]
      ,[RecieveEmailUpdates]
      ,[ParticipateInTisSurvey]
      ,[RecieveSMSUpdates]
}
```

Job table and job query table has one to one relation ship based on Job ID. Also Job query table has one to one relation with agent based on agent ID. But for isMigrated true in jobs table the agent Id would always be NULL.

I want to combine those two queries to do INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN based on the ismigrated value. As migrated jobs won't have any agentID in job queries table.

Let me know if further details are required.

Comment: Please explain.  Sample data and desired results are helpful.  For instance, why not just put `union all` between the queries?

Comment: Both Queries will return Identical results. They will return all the Columns with agents .. but for J.Ismigrated = 1 if I do a do a INNER JOIN instead of the outer join it will just return zero results. Because AgentId would be null in that job query table. I have got a single view and I want to use inner join and outer join based on the isMigrated value. as Inner join won't work for is Migrated Value.

Comment: You need to elaborate more and give us more context to help you. What is the Schema of each table and the Relationship between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always do the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and add the `WHERE` condition to simulate `INNER JOIN` functionality for `isMigrated = 0`.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM [tisonline].[dbo].[Jobs] AS j
LEFT OUTER JOIN [tisonline].dbo.JobQueries AS jq 
ON j.JobID = jq.JobID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [tisonline]. dbo.Agents AS agt ON agt.AgentID = jq.AgentID
WHERE j.isMigrated = 1 
    OR agt.AgentID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I was just thinking what if I only do a left outer joins without the where condition as agentId will only belong to single agent anyway. I can't really test the query as there are no migrated jobs in my local dev environment. But this one seem like will solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an `OUTER JOIN` will do everything of an `INNER JOIN` and then some more. I'd modify your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like this:

```
   SELECT TOP 1000 *
   FROM [tisonline].[dbo].[Jobs] AS j
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [tisonline].dbo.JobQueries AS jq 
   ON j.JobID = jq.JobID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [tisonline]. dbo.Agents AS agt ON agt.AgentID = jq.AgentID
   where j.isMigrated = 1
   OR (j.isMigrated = 0 AND jp.JobID IS NOT NULL AND agt.AgentID IS NOT NULL)
```