# Conditional statement to determine inner join or left outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have a large millions+ rows of record that in a table that I want to do an inner join when a parameter is provided, if not do a filter based search. Long term solution is to split up the logic, but I need some assistance in the short term.

I'm trying to do something like below:

```sql
params:
@movie_ids int_table (optional passing in a table of only ints here) 
@filter_name
@filter_genre
@filter_actor_name

DECLARE @id_count = sets movie id count here or 0; 

SELECT 
      m.Id
      m.Name
      m.ShortName
      m.Genre
      m.ImageUrl
FROM Movies m WITH(NOLOCK)
IF movie_ids <> 0 
  BEGIN
    INNER JOIN @movie_ids mids
      ON mids.id = m.Id
  END
ELSE 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN code_genres cg
    ON m.GenreId = cg.Id
  INNER JOIN Actors a
    ON a.name LIKE '%@filter_actor_name%'
END
WHERE m.Name LIKE '%filter_name%'
OR m.ShortName LIKE '%filter_name%'
```

Sorry I couldn't provide the actual stored procedure since I'm not the original writer. The problem in short term I'm trying to figure out is to find out if I can do this conditional joins.

Currently it has a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a where clause that suppose to do the conditional, but the amount of data it is returning before the filter occurs is too much - too slow. [Something like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063666/inner-join-or-left-outer-join-based-on-condition)

Let me know if I can provide more details.

(Long terms solution is done - split up the logic from sql, but I need something for now)

Comment: I dont think its possible to do what you want.  In the past for this type of issue I use left joins onto filter tables and in where clause do something like where (@param is null or filtertable.col = @param), but this make a slow query plan.  Best option is dynamic sql

Comment: Nolock is not "free" magic - there are consequences to its use. So don't use it until you understand those consequences. Erland discusses many different approaches to this [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Programnik mentioned, you can go for dynamic sql here. You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) = '';

@sql = @sql + 'SELECT 
      m.Id
      m.Name
      m.ShortName
      m.Genre
      m.ImageUrl
FROM Movies m WITH(NOLOCK)';

IF movie_ids <> 0 
  BEGIN
    @sql = @sql + ' INNER JOIN @movie_ids mids
      ON mids.id = m.Id';
END
ELSE 
  @sql = @sql + ' LEFT OUTER JOIN code_genres cg
    ON m.GenreId = cg.Id
  INNER JOIN Actors a
    ON a.name LIKE' +'%@filter_actor_name%';
END

@sql = @sql + ' WHERE m.Name LIKE' + '%filter_name%';
@sql = @sql + ' OR m.ShortName LIKE' + '%filter_name%';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: += does not support in SQL,use sql = sql + 'your string'